# Can anyone tune given query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-tuning, groupwise-maximum

Pls help to tune this query

```
select
    substr(Extend(current,year to second)- extend(outr.eventDateTime,year to second)+INTERVAL(300)  MINUTE(3) TO MINUTE,-8) as duration, 
    else 'Hold' end as state 
    from 
    A as outr,
    B as rs 
    where  
    eventDateTime = (select max(eventDateTime) from A as innr  where outr.aID=innr.aID and outr.pID=innr.pID)
    and eventDateTime >= Date(current) 
    and rs.rID = outr.aID
    and rs.pID = outr.pID 
    order by rName
```

Comment: add output of `EXPLAIN  PLAN`.... , and DDL  for the used tables, and the definition of the UDF `Extend`.

Comment: yes, show output of `explain select substr....` and  `show create table A` and `show create table B` and `select version()`.  also say how long the query is taking and what your goal is for how long you would like it to take

Comment: Yes, the database server is down now. Can you tell me exact command to run. As I am a beginner in mysql. so I can get all results and tell you.

Comment: Please use modern join syntax, not that comma-separated syntax from the 80's.

Comment: Also, please prepend each column with the table name (or alias) so we can understand where each column comes from. It may be evident for you, but not for us. Specifically `eventDateTime` an `rName`.

Comment: Syntax error?? "else"??

Answer (score 0):

For starters, add this index:

```
INDEX(aid, pid)
```

This smells like a "groupwise max".  See the tag I added.